# How to enable mod_headers on centos

Tags: centos, apache-2.2

When I installed apache2 I didnt do ./configure --enable-headers. How can I enable it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wait - you compiled Apache from source? Do you have a need for that or could you just use Apache 2 version provided by CentOS? You can install that with `yum install httpd`.

Comment: I didn't know that. Is  there anything I can do now? Maybe reinstalling? How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled Apache with DSO support you can compile mod_headers and load it dynamically.

You will want to use a tool called apxs to do this.

Alternatively use the OS RPM or rebuild apache.